# Framework7 Smart Select show selected item

Tags: html, html-framework-7

i have this little smart select:

```
<div class="list-block">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="item-link smart-select" data-back-on-select="true" data-open-in="popup">
                <select name="projects" id="projects">
                  <option value="0" selected>Please choose...</option>
                  <option value="1" >House build</option>
                </select>
                <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-title">Aufträge</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the user select an item, I created a cookie an wrote the value in it. After a reload or closing the page I read in the cookie an select the item. That works. But, I alaways the "Please choose" entry and not the selected item. But when I click on the list the correct item is select but then close the list I see again Please choose.
This is how I select the value:

```
$$("#projects").val(getCookie("timerTasks"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who need this answer at this time, the  `find("option:selected")`  does not work for this purpose anymore. Use `find("option:checked")` instead.

Final code would be

```
$$("#projects").val(getCookie("timerTasks")).parent().find('.item-title').html($$("#projects").find("option:checked").text());
```

Answer (score 2):

@tinyCoder got it almost right, except you need to update `.item-after`, not `.item-title`. `.item-title` is the "label" of smart select, and `.item-after` displays the selected value.

Also, since `.html()` will render HTML, and we only need text, I think it's more appropriate to use `.text()`. So, my one-liner would look like this:

```
$$("#projects").val(getCookie("timerTasks")).parent().find('.item-after').text($$("#projects").find("option:selected").text());
```

Framework7 v1.6.5 (September 2017.)

Comment: Thank you for the update Tommy, I'm too far away of Framework7 now and I really don't know the recent news, it was having compatibility issues that made me go native.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ran into this before. You have to update the `item-title` class after choosing the value from the cookie:

In details:

```
// Select your value
$$("#projects").val(getCookie("timerTasks"));

// Selected value text
var selected_text = $$("#projects").find("option:selected").text();

// Change item-title
$$("#projects").parent().find('.item-title').html(selected_text);
```

One Line:

```
$$("#projects").val(getCookie("timerTasks")).parent().find('.item-title').html($$("#projects").find("option:selected").text());
```

You can see [this is a common issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=smart%20select%20) there, I'm wondering why it is not fixed yet.